# Change default keypress behaviour of Form.Item in INput type to onChange (tab out)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

While using the antd library and using the Form component having an  inside of  always triggers a FormChanged event every single key pressed.

How do i change this behaviour to trigger the FormChanged event on when the user completes or tabs out of the  text box.

> 

```html
<Form onValuesChange={this.onFormChanged}>
  <Form.Item>
      <Input />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: you can't, since state is tracked by every keystroke. Its like asking "when i click on something can i stop a click event happening"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library per se, but you could use an onBlur event on the input itself.